# require.js require a module with index.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs, chutzpah

So I'm trying to set up Typescript and Chutzpah for testing purposes. Typescript is set up to output in this format:

```
define(['require', 'exports', './someModule'], function(require, exports, someModule) {
    //examplecode
});
```

Which works fine, the problem occurs when someModule is actually a directory with an index.js.

```
/app
  app.js
  /someModule
    index.js
```

require.js is unable to resolve someModule in this way and the test fails.

Is there any way to tell require.js that this is a module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RequireJS won't automatically check for the presence of `index.js` and load that as your module. You need to tell RequireJS that when you want to load `someModule`, it should load `someModule/index`. I'd set a [`map`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-map) in my call to `require.config`:

```
require.config({
  [ ... ]
  map: {
    '*': {
        someModule: 'someModule/index',
    }
  },
});
```

You have to adjust the name you give there so that it is a path relative to your `baseUrl`. It's not clear from the information you give in your question what it should be.

(For the record, there's also a [`packages`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#packages) setting that you could probably tweak to do what you want but putting something `packages` says "this is a package", which is not what you appear to have here. So I would not use it for what you are trying to do.)

Comment: Perfect, Thanks! Is there any way to do this dynamically or does every package I use that has an index need to be defined here?

Comment: You need to do it for every module. There's no support to turn this on in some sort of dynamic way or use pattern matching. The `'*'` you can use in `map` is a really a hardcoded name that means "in all modules" and it is only significant as a key of `map` itself, and nowhere else. `map` would not understand things like `foo*`, nor could you do something like `map: { '*': { '*': '...'}}` The second `*` would be interpreted literally by RequireJS as "a module named `*`" and not as "all modules"..

Comment: This doesn't work for me, not sure why.  Require ignores the map setting

Comment: I think if your index exports all features of the module/package, the `packages` config is what you want. For me, `map` doesn't work, because my `index.js` has local dependencies, which are then changed to `someModule/index/dep`, although they should remain `someModule/dep`. For me `packages:[{name: 'someModule', main: 'index'}]` works like a charm. (also works with e.g. `subdir/someModule`)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't like the configuration in `map` either. The most simple way I accomplished this was writing a plugin for require.

Let's name the plugin `mod`, where it is to be used as `mod!module/someModule`, you can also call it `index` as in `index!module/someModule`, whatever suits you best.

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
   // loading module/someModule/index.js with `mod!`      
   var someModule = require('mod!module/someModule');

   // whatever this is about ..
   module.exports = { .. };
});
```

So lets assume you have `paths` set in require's configuration with some sort of project structure:

```
- app
  - modules
    - someModule/index.js        // the index we want to load
    - someModule/..
    - someModule/..
    - etc
  - plugins
    - mod.js                     // plugin to load a module with index.js
```

Requires config:

```
require.config({
   paths: {
      'module': 'app/modules',

      // the plugin we're going to use so 
      // require knows what mod! stands for
      'mod': 'app/plugins/mod.js'
   }
});
```

To read all the aspects of how to write a plugin, [read the docs at requirejs.org](http://requirejs.org/docs/plugins.html). The simplest version would be to just rewrite the `name` of the requested "module" you are attempting to access and pass it back to `load`.

*app/plugins/mod.js*

```
(function() {
    define(function () {
        function parse(name, req) {
            return req.toUrl(name + '/index.js');
        }

        return {
            normalize: function(name, normalize) {
                return normalize(name);
            },
            load:function (name, req, load) {
                req([parse(name, req)], function(o) {
                    load(o);
                });
            }
        };
    });
})();
```

**This is not production code**, it's just a simple way to demonstrate that requires config wasn't meant to solve problems like this.